# Is $xRy \iff x+y = 0$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

$R$ is a relation on real numbers. $xRy \iff x+y = 0 $.
Is it an equivalence relation?

My answer is no

proof:

-(Reflexive) let $x = a$ , $aRa \iff 2a=0$.
 Since $2a = 0$ doesn't hold for every real number $a$, $R$ is not reflexive.

Since $R$ isn't reflexive, $R$ is not an equivalence relation.

Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: Yes you're correct, $R$ isn't reflexive, so it's not an equivalence relation.

Comment: okay thx again :) .

Comment: No prob, yw again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not only correct, it is almost the most straightforward approach you could take. Nicely done!

The only improvement I would suggest is that you demonstrate a particular real number $a$ for which $a\:R\:a$ *fails* to hold. For example, you could just say: "Since $1+1=2\ne 0,$ then $1\:R\:1$ fails to hold, and so $R$ is not an equivalence relation on the real numbers."